# Multiple directives on one page with ng-model, bindToController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

I've created an email subscribe directive, that you attach to a form and on submit, it fires off the email to Campaign Monitor, yada yada ya.

I'm running into a weird issue though, where ng-model is breaking out of an isolated scope and bindToController.

Angular Directive:

```
    angular.module('quiip.directives')
    .directive('subscribeToNewsletter', subscribeToNewsletterDirective);

    function subscribeToNewsletterDirective(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'subscribe',
            controller: subscribeToNewsletterCtrl,
            link: function(scope, el){
                el.addClass('subscribe-to-newsletter');
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML form, general structure. This varies depending on where the form is used. This is hard coded (i.e. not a template):

```
    <form subscribe-to-newsletter ng-submit="subscribe.submitEmailSubscribe()" ng-class="{ error : subscribe.states.error, success : subscribe.states.success }">
        <div class="status-icon loading" ng-show="subscribe.states.loading"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="status-icon success" ng-show="subscribe.states.success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Subscribed!</div>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="subscribe.email">
        <button type="submit" class="hollow">Subscribe to newsletter</button>
    </form>
```

Another example of the form:

```
    <form class="row" subscribe-to-newsletter ng-submit="subscribe.submitEmailSubscribe()" ng-class="{ error : subscribe.states.error, success : subscribe.states.success }">
        <div class="status-icon loading" ng-show="subscribe.states.loading"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
        <div class="status-icon success" ng-show="subscribe.states.success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Subscribed!</div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <input type="email" ng-model="subscribe.email" placeholder="email" name="email-address">
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <button type="submit" class="expand">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

As you can see [in this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryfeg5i0mzhg1ht/Screenshot%202015-10-23%2019.13.08.png?dl=0), the `ng-model` is escaping both isolated scope and controllerAs/bindToController (I'm not even sure I need to use both?) and propagating across the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your directive. You are just using the same model for both fields `ng-model="subscribe.email"`.

Comment: Thanks - I was under the impression that `subscribe.email` would be using the subscribe object on the isolated directive scope - thus not conflicting across the page. I was using ng-model to access the email value within the isolated directive scope!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a directive for isolating scope vs a directive for manipulating the DOM.

#### Isolate scope

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) creating an isolate scope allows you to

> separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope.

If you want to isolate the scope of your form inside a parent scope and expose the model to that parent scope you could implement it like:

```
<!-- parent template -->
<div> <!-- just an example parent template -->

    <subscribe-to-newsletter subscribe-email="subscribe.email"></subscribe-to-newsletter>

</div>
```

Then you have a separate template file for your form code:

```
<form ng-submit="subscribe.submitEmailSubscribe()".... <!-- note no use of directive name here -->
    ...
</form>
```

Then your directive looks like this

```
// subscribeToNewsletter.directive.js
angular.module('quiip.directives')
.directive('subscribeToNewsletter', subscribeToNewsletterDirective);

function subscribeToNewsletterDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            subscribeEmail: '=' // bi-directional binding to the model passed into your template handy for attaching data to a parent form object
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'subscribe',
        controller: subscribeToNewsletterCtrl,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'path/to/your/form/template'
    }
}
```

#### Manipulating the DOM

To manipulate the DOM then you can create a directive that returns a link function (pretty much what you're already doing but without the isolate scope).

A good example of this is [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom). For your coding style your directive could look like:

```
angular.module('quiip.directives')
    .directive('subscribeToNewsletter', subscribeToNewsletterDirective);

    function subscribeToNewsletterDirective() {
        return {
            link: link
        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass('subscribe-to-newsletter');
        }
    }
```

#### Finally...

If you have two different forms in different views both using the same model name then it would be better to have a different controller for each view to avoid namespacing collisions.

Comment: Thanks @br3w5 for the awesomely detailed answer... The problem with using an element directive is that I can't have a different layout for the form for each instance. That was the idea with using an attribute instead - I could attach the functionality to any form and it would work. I guess I want to isolate the email field within the directive so that it _doesn't_ propagate to a parent scope. I could use el.find('input') val to skirt around the ng-model but that doesn't seem like the angular way...

Comment: So is the purpose of the directive only to take the email address and send it off to campaign monitor?

Comment: why not use a service or factory for that?